# Should the expression "to treat people with dignity" be,instead "to accord dignity to people"?

Tags: awkwardexpressions

The expression "to treat people with dignity" seems to me to be incorrect, or at least expressed awkwardly.

A person cannot treat another person with dignity, but a person ***can*** accord dignity to another person. "To treat a person with dignity" seems to be saying more about the person doing the treating than the person receiving the treating.

In other words, if I treat you with dignity, I am treating you in a dignified manner. On the other hand, by according dignity to another person I am acknowledging the person ***already has*** dignity, or is dignified by simply being who he or she is.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/152197/discussion-on-question-by-rhetorician-should-the-expression-to-treat-people-wit); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: How exactly can this question be answered by 'consulting a dictionary'? A dictionary may confirm that the phrase is used this way (which the OP obviously knows), but it is not clear how it could resolve the syntactical paradox that the question is about.

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be a mix up of the first two definitions of dignity as provided by the [Merriam-Webster dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dignity):

> dignity
>
> 1 : formal reserve or seriousness of manner, appearance, or language
>
> 2
> : the quality or state of being worthy, honored, or esteemed
>
> 3 a :
> high rank, office, or position b : a legal title of nobility or honor
>
> 4 archaic : dignitary

*To treat someone with dignity* accords with the first definition.

Comment: The syntax of 'A treats B with dignity' indeed leads one to expect that the first sense is intended; the problem that the question is about is that the formulation is often used with the second sense intended (with the dignity being the B's dignity).

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to one person "treating" another, for there to be dignity, it must be shared, and become a property of the relationship. It must be displayed by each and assumed by each in the other. If either party departs much from that, "dignity" evaporates.

Answer (score 0):

In fact "to accord dignity to someone" is pretty much a part of what one is doing when one is "treating someone with dignity"; but that is not all: the action of the verb has to be  taken into account. The function of "with" in this construction is the following.

> (**SOED**) **ith** **23** Indicating a circumstance accompanying the action expressed by the verb.
> C BAX He married again—with seemingly better results. B. MALAMUD She greeted him .. with a fresh kiss. A. GARVE He went .. off .. with scarcely a word. E. TAYLOR He .. got up with a jerk. *Oxford Mail* People went hopping mad .. with all sorts of crazy capers for charity

It should be clear after reading the facts collected below that the function of "with" is not to indicate the manner, as for instance in "The witness left the room with dignity." (the definition of "dignity" that applies being the first one in the OLD reference infra).

> ([OLD](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/dignity?q=dignity)) **dignity** noun
>
> 1. [uncountable, singular] a calm and serious manner that deserves respect
>
> - She accepted the criticism with quiet dignity.
> - He brings a quiet dignity to the role.
> - His aristocratic voice gives him an air of dignity and power.
>
> 2. [uncountable] the fact of being given honour and respect by people
>
> - the dignity of work
> - The terminally ill should be allowed to die with dignity.
>
> 3. [uncountable] a sense of your own importance and value
>
> - It's difficult to preserve your dignity when you have no job and no home.

It is apparent that the only possibility is "2."; the example "… to die with dignity", which, by the way, can be easily interpreted as depending on the first definition, gives  a striking parallel: death is some sort of "treatment" to which is submitted the person (never mind the agent), and dignity is an accompanying circumstance.

It will be seen from a reading of the references now proposed that in the fields of psychology and philosophy the meaning given to this expression has to do with the granting to the person so treated of a certain  status. There is not the idea of "being" (found in the first definition of the dictionary), but instead that of "giving" (in the second definition.

In this first reference it will be considered by some that the author stretches the notion somewhat excessively, but the idea of conferring or acknowledging a certain status is inescapable.

> [Living With Dignity: How to Treat People as You Would Like Them to treat You - Anthony Ekanem · 2020](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Living_With_Dignity/KMfjDwAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22treat+people+with+dignity%22&pg=PT4&printsec=frontcover)
>
> Many people, regardless of their race, education and social status, do not understand what dignity is, or what it means to treat people with dignity. So we have a collective ignorance about all matters relating to dignity. And because of the ignorance, even good people with good intentions can violate others without knowing it.
>
> **Living With Dignity** is an attempt to address this ignorance. And as the subtitle of the book suggests, dignity is all about how to treat people, the same way you would like them to treat you. The core elements of dignity discussed in the book include:
> **Accepting people as they are** - people want others to treat them well no matter their race, religion, ethnicity, gender, or sexual orientation.
> **Acknowledging people** - for their hard work and a job well done.
> **Safety of people** - make people feel safe both physically and psychologically, so they feel free from humiliation.
> […]
> You treat someone with dignity when you lend a helping hand.
> […]
> Give considerate advice.
> […]

This next reference highlights the notion of "giving in a certain way" as tantamount to bestowing dignity upon the person one is dealing with.

> ([Leading with Dignity: How to Create a Culture That Brings ... - Page 27
> Donna Hicks · 2019](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Leading_with_Dignity/G1RnDwAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22treat+people+with+dignity%22&pg=PA27&printsec=frontcover))
>
> Monique Valcour, a management academic and consultant, describes a common theme in reports from her students: "Leaders who undermine employee autonomy are corrosive because they undermine the dignity of work". She warns that this is a very serious matter because "dignity is fundamental to well-being and to human organizational thriving". She writes: "The enlightened leader knows how to treat people with dignity".
> Sociologist Randy Hodson's comprehensive analysis of dignity in the workplace points in the same direction. Managers who treat people with dignity—who give them a sense of autonomy and independence to work in the way that best suits them, create an open and trusting environment where employees are acknowledged and recognized for their good work, and treat them as a way that enhances their self-worth and the worth of others—are those who succeed as leaders.

In the third reference the notion of "giving" (respect) is evident.

([Human Dignity in Bioethics and Law - Charles Foster · 2011](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Human_Dignity_in_Bioethics_and_Law/_x7cBAAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22treat+people+with+dignity%22&pg=PA72&printsec=frontcover))

> Dignity is concerned with how people feel, think and behave in relation to the worth or value of themselves and others. To treat people with dignity is to treat them as being of worth, in a way that is respectful of them as valued individuals.

I'll say in conclusion that there appears to be no error of logic in this expression. Although it is easy to confuse the accompanying circumstance with a manner having no effect on the person being treated (and even easier to assimilate it to a manner affecting that person), and thereby think that solely the person doing the treating is being characterized, it remains that the dignity is something that is granted and/or acknowledged by the person doing the treating; there is therefore no question of a dignified manner of doing the treating. The notion of an acknowledgement of an initial dignity of the person being treated is however part and parcel of a treatment with dignity. In the end it can be said that the expression is conceived as best as possible to express what you think it should.